# How to split and colour a part of a pen drawn object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to illustrator. I have the below picture I created with a pen tool:

[image]

How do I select the bottom part of the picture like this:

[image]

I want to keep the rest of the shape and the portion that is selected I want to colour it differently. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** (under the Shape Builder Tool).

Pick a color, select the art and start clicking to color.

When done, click the `Expand` button in the *Control Bar* across the top of the screen.

Comment: I tried the instructions but everytime I choose a colour and then select the shape with the  "Selection Tool (V)", I end up with the whole shape coloured. Is there another way to select the section I need?

Comment: ahhh just figured it out. Brilliant instructions!

Comment: I can't tell if that's sarcastic, @Dan `:)` If the instructions aren't clear, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott, definitely not sarcastic. I was choosing the wrong option. One point to note though the “Live Paint Bucket Tool” is not under the “Shape Builder Tool” in the default illustrator CC, it’s hidden in the “...” menu. Thanks for a really great explanation though.